# What is Site Content and structure in Sharepoint Online and what it is used for or how to create a site structure?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, user-controls

1.What is Site Content and structure in Sharepoint Online and what it is used for or how to create a site structure? Please provide me some good links or videos on activating and using it. I searched via google and cant find any relevant document about this. Thanks.

1. Is it possible to use User Controls (.ascx) with Sandboxed solutions for SharePoint Online, if not is there any other way to do it with the codes. Please do guide me through this.

Thanks and Regards,
Surya.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [videos](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/introductory-videos-for-sharepoint-online-for-enterprises-HA102604631.aspx) that you can use to learn SharePoint online.

Site Content and Structure page is a tool for site administrators to manage site content and structure and that is no different than other SharePoint versions.

**No**, you can't use User Controls in Sandbox solutions. You best chance is to develop web parts instead of user controls. However, you also cannot use Visual web parts (because Visual WP also contains ascx)